# What's the pronunciation of "явью"

Tags: грамматика, произношение

I got this a message from my friend with the following photo in which it says: "

> Новый год уже совсем близко... Пусть Новогодняя сказка станет **явью**,  **а**
>   все мечты исполнятся.

As I understand it says:

> The new year is quite close, let the new year fairy tales become
>   reality **and** all dreams come true.

My questions about it are two:

1) What's the pronunciation of явью? (Yavyu or Yivu? two different local people told me two different pronunciations)

2) Why does it use "**a**" instead of "**и**" (=and)?

[image]

Comment: please, tend to ask one question per post

Comment: whoever told you yivu is a dirty liar )))

Comment: @shabunc: this or they might have confused it with _наяву_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right pronunciation of word **"явью"** is **[ˈjævjʊ]**.

The conjunction **"a"** among others has two meanings: **"but"** and **"and"**.
It can be used in meaning **"and"** when we need to show the heterogeneity described in the two connected sentences. Compare:

> Пусть Новогодняя сказка станет явью и все мечты - тоже!

и

> Пусть Новогодняя сказка станет явью, а все мечты исполнятся!

The first sentence implies that both parts of a complex sentence are about becoming a reality:

> Пусть Новогодняя сказка станет явью и все мечты тоже [станут явью]!

In the second sentence, the first part is about fairy tales, and second - about dreams, and in that sentence fairy tales become a reality, **but** dreams will come true (**come true**, not **become to reality**). So we use **"a"** instead of **"и"**.

But if you use **"и"** in your sample, it won't be mistake. It will be just a slight change in the tone of the phrase.

Answer (score 1):

The pronunciation of *явью* is *[ˈjävʲjʊ]*.

*А* is used instead of *и* because the other clause starts with a noun and has a different verb.

Should the sentence be put this way:

> Пусть станет явью новогодняя сказка, и исполнятся все мечты!

, it would have been used with *и*

Comment: Здесь (https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%8F%D0%B2%D1%8C) предлагают использовать **"æ"** при записи произношения первого слога.

Comment: @IvanOlshansky: you can use it like that if you really pronounce the _в_ fully palatalized. Most people speaking Moscow dialect don't (i.e. they pronounce something closer to _явъю_, with a harder _в_)

Comment: @IvanOlshansky The Wikipedia article for æ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-open_front_unrounded_vowel) has several examples of its pronunciation, and the example for "пять" doesn't sound similar to any other example on that page, for me at least. Is it merely psychological that native Russian speakers hear [æ] between soft consonants as [a], or is it really [a] or [ä] sound in that position?

Comment: @Joker_vD, To be honest, different people say it in different ways.

Comment: @Joker_vD: _[æ], [a]_ and _[ä]_ are allophones, different physical sounds for the same phoneme (the thing which is perceived as a basic building unit of a word). Phonemes are written using slashes, like this: _/я/_. What the speakers of a language "hear" (perceive) is phonemes, while non-speakers hear physical sounds (or, rather, phonemes of their own language close to those physical sounds). Things in square brackets are  frequencies and shapes on an oscilloscope, things in slashes are images within one's brain

Comment: @Joker_vD: So answering your question, Russian speakers hear _/я/_ when their ears receive _[æ]_ between two soft consonants, and they hear an off-key, distorted _/я/_ when their ears receive _[a]_ in the same position, between two soft consonants.